# ArcObjects - WFS:

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, wfs, java, data-interoperability

Has anybody an example concerning accessing data from a WFS server by using the DataInteropability in ArcObjects?

I'm getting the right field definistion, but don't know how to read the data.

Here my current Java code:

```
FMEWorkspaceFactory fmeWorkspaceFactory = new FMEWorkspaceFactory();
IPlugInWorkspaceHelper plugInWorkspaceHelper = fmeWorkspaceFactory.openWorkspace("C:\\temp");
FMEWorkspaceHelper fmeWorkspaceHelper = new FMEWorkspaceHelper(plugInWorkspaceHelper);
FMEDatasetHelper fmeDatasetHelper = new FMEDatasetHelper(fmeWorkspaceHelper.openDataset("test.fdl"));
IFields fields = fmeDatasetHelper.getFields(0);
```

I suppose, I have to use the "fetchAll" method of the FMEDatasetHelper class.

Comment: Problem solved by using this code: [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/bugramovic/fme_arcobjects_interop_example/overview)

Comment: When you get a chance would you be able to copy your Comment (solution) to an Answer that you then Accept, please?  It is quite permissible to do this and gets one more Unanswered Question off our list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the code below. Full code in git repository can be here: https://bitbucket.org/bugramovic/fme_arcobjects_interop_example

```
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    FMEWorkspaceFactory fmeWorkspaceFactory = new FMEWorkspaceFactory();
    IPlugInWorkspaceHelper plugInWorkspaceHelper = fmeWorkspaceFactory.openWorkspace( pathToFdlFiles );
    FMEWorkspaceHelper fmeWorkspaceHelper = new FMEWorkspaceHelper( plugInWorkspaceHelper );
    printDatasets( fmeWorkspaceHelper );

    IPlugInDatasetHelper dsHelper = fmeWorkspaceHelper.openDataset( fdlFile );
    FMEDatasetHelper fmeDatasetHelper = new FMEDatasetHelper( dsHelper );

    printClasses( fmeDatasetHelper );

    out.println( "Class-name:" + fmeDatasetHelper.getClassName( featureClassIdx ) );
    IFields fields = fmeDatasetHelper.getFields( featureClassIdx );
    printFields( fields );

    FMEReader reader = new FMEReader( fmeDatasetHelper );
    List<ArrayRowBuffer> lst = reader.readFeatures( featureClassIdx );
    for (ArrayRowBuffer el : lst) {
        out.println( el );
    }
```